# Abstract factory method; changing the factory passed to an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, design-patterns

In this scenario the replicator for Star Trek: TNG has been on the fritz and Guinan has asked me to fix it.  Because the replicator doesn't know what drinks to make until someone tells it to, we decided to use the Abstract Factory pattern to create the drinks

```
public abstract class BoozeFactory
    {
        //create abstract methods
        public abstract Whiskey CreateWhiskey();
        public abstract Rum CreateRum();

    }
    public class BlantonsFactory : BoozeFactory
    {
        public override Whiskey CreateWhiskey()
        {
            return new BlantonsWhiskey();
        }
        public override Rum CreateRum()
        {
            return new BlantonsRum();
        }
    }
    public class VobFactory : BoozeFactory
    {
        public override Whiskey CreateWhiskey()
        {
            return new VobWhiskey();
        }
        public override Rum CreateRum()
        {
            return new VobRum();
        }
    }
```

Then we drilled down into the brands that the replicator can spit out

```
 public abstract class Whiskey
    {
        public int Proof { get; set; }
        public abstract void DrinkingMethod();

    }
    public abstract class Rum
    {
        public int Proof { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class BlantonsWhiskey : Whiskey
    {
        public override void DrinkingMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is {0}, you should sip it",GetType().Name);
        }
    }
    class VobWhiskey : Whiskey
    {
        public override void DrinkingMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is {0}, you should shoot it",GetType().Name);

        }
    }
    class BlantonsRum : Rum
    {
    }
    class VobRum : Rum
    {
    }
```

Then we decided to reprogram Data to be a lush

```
class Drinker
    {
        public BoozeFactory BoozeFactory { get; set; }
        public Whiskey Whiskey { get; set; }
        public Rum Rum { get; set; }

        public Drinker(BoozeFactory b)
        {
            //BoozeFactory is abstract and we will have to pass either a Blantons
            //or Vob factory to the constructor.  This way, the Whiskey and Rum
            //properties can depend on what is passed to the constructor at runtime
            BoozeFactory = b;
            Whiskey = BoozeFactory.CreateWhiskey();
            Rum = BoozeFactory.CreateRum();
        }
    }
```

Here were the results from our test

```
Drinker data = new Drinker(new BlantonsFactory());
        data.Whiskey.DrinkingMethod();
        //woot, output is correct

        //the DrinkingMethod in the VobFactory class gives us different output
        data.BoozeFactory = new VobFactory(); //this is what's causing problems
        data.BoozeFactory.CreateWhiskey();
        data.Whiskey.DrinkingMethod();
        //even though the BoozeFactory property of data has been changed
        //the output hasn't changed

        BoozeFactory b = new VobFactory();
        data.Whiskey = b.CreateWhiskey();
        data.Whiskey.DrinkingMethod();
        //now the output is correct
```

Why is it that unless a new named instance of BoozeFactory is instantiated that the second call to `data.Whiskey.DrinkingMethod()` is ignored, but when I create the named instance and test it, it works?

Comment: What exactly are the 3 lines of output from the test results?

Comment: The first call to data.Whiskey.DrinkingMethod() is `Console.WriteLine("This is {0}, you should sip it",GetType().Name);` and the second call should be `Console.WriteLine("This is {0}, you should shoot it",GetType().Name);`

Comment: This is because of the overriden DrinkingMethod that comes from the abstract class `Whiskey`

Comment: I know what's supposed to be called, I wouldn't be attempting to answer this if I didn't understand inheritance and abstraction. I'm asking what's the exact console output, line for line? i.e. This is VobWhiskey, you should sip it (\n) This is VobWhiskey, you should sip it (\n) This is BlantonsWhiskey, you should shoot it

Comment: The first call is "This is BlantonsWhiskey, you should sip it" and the second is "This is VobWhiskey, you should shoot it".

Comment: There should be 3 lines, you call DrinkingMethod 3 times.

Comment: Scratch that, I know the problem

Comment: @wootscootinboogie SO is not for learning. Its for solving problems. Your "problem" shows total lack of basic understanding of OO programming, which should be fixed by any solid online tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
//the DrinkingMethod in the VobFactory class gives us different output
data.BoozeFactory = new VobFactory(); //this is what's causing problems
data.BoozeFactory.CreateWhiskey();
data.Whiskey.DrinkingMethod();
```

You never assign the new whiskey to the data.Whiskey property, you create it and then discard it instantly. You should be writing your second line as this:

```
data.Whiskey = data.BoozeFactory.CreateWhiskey();
```

Or, better yet, have the drinker have a method that does this for it.